# AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lstm' (type LSTM)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have this error when I add TimeDistributed function to LSTM:

AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lstm' (type LSTM).      'LSTMCell' object has no attribute 'kernel'

for this code :

```
model = Sequential()
# define CNN model
model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(80, 1))))

# model.add(TimeDistributed(LSTM(128, input_shape=(80,1), return_sequences=True)))
# define LSTM model
# model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')

historyCNN = model.fit(traininp, trainout, epochs=100 ,validation_data=(validinp, validout))
```

I upgraded keras and tensorflow, I got sure that I m using correct input and output data.
But I have no idea what can the problem be

Answer (score 0):

LSTM layer is already time distributed layer, you don't need to add TimeDistributed to it. Please try just:

```
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(80, 1)))
```